# Removing All Elements with feature X from Array, except the latest

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, algorithm

I have the following object:

```
[
  { name: "Peter", id: 25, job: "carpenter" },
  { name: "Peter", id: 25, job: "shelf maker" },
  { name: "John", no: 20, job: "student" },
  { name: "John", id: 20, job: "university student" },
  { name: "John", id: 20, job: "student at uni still" },
  { name: "Jack", id: 20, job: "university student" }
]
```

I would like to go through this array and whenever `name` and `id` are identical I would like to only keep one entry, namely the one appearing *the latest* in the array, and discard all the rest. How would I do this?

I have tried

```
for(let i=0;i<people.length;i++) {
const person = people[i];
const result = people.filter(person => person.id === id && person.name === name);

people[i] = person;
}
```

... but this doesn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? How would you approach this?

Comment: Please tell the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduceRight` to build new array starting the iteration from the end of the array, and also `Map` as accumulator value to store `key - value` pairs.

```js
const data = [{"name":"Peter","id":25,"job":"carpenter"},{"name":"Peter","id":25,"job":"shelf maker"},{"name":"John","no":20,"job":"student"},{"name":"John","id":20,"job":"university student"},{"name":"John","id":20,"job":"student at uni still"},{"name":"Jack","id":20,"job":"university student"}]

const map = data.reduceRight((r, e) => {
  const key = `${e.name}|${e.id}`;
  if (!r.has(key)) r.set(key, e);
  return r;
}, new Map);

const uniq = [...map.values()];
console.log(uniq)
```

Comment: Nice approach, I was considering using reverse() but didn't bother in the end. I would assume this solution is faster

Comment: @Kobe Thanks, I would also assume its faster since omit reverse step.

Comment: The only downfall I've found with this answer is having to spread out the values again, other than that, reduceRIght is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd `reduce` into an object, whose keys are the ID and name put together, and whose values are the latest object with a particular ID and name found so far, and then get the object's values:

```js
const input=[{name:"Peter",id:25,job:"carpenter"},{name:"Peter",id:25,job:"shelf maker"},{name:"John",no:20,job:"student"},{name:"John",id:20,job:"university student"},{name:"John",id:20,job:"student at uni still"},{name:"Jack",id:20,job:"university student"}];

const output = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, obj) => {
    const { name, id } = obj;
    const key = `${name}_${id}`;
    a[key] = obj;
    return a;
  }, {})
);
console.log(output);
```

Computational complexity is `O(N)`, since there are no nested loops.

Comment: Is this not O(2N) since you are using `Object.values`?

Comment: Big O complexity ignores those sorts of factors that don't depend on the input size (like the scalar multiplier 2 here), because they're irrelvant in the limit - it's even true that `O(1000) === O(1)`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example .

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for clarifying. I haven't looked into big O notation too much, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduceRight` with a `Map` to check if the object already exists in the accumulator - if it does, ignore it, else push the new object, and new key + index pair to the map:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "Peter", id: 25, job: "carpenter" },
  { name: "Peter", id: 25, job: "shelf maker" },
  { name: "John", no: 20, job: "student" },
  { name: "John", id: 20, job: "university student" },
  { name: "John", id: 20, job: "student at uni still" },
  { name: "Jack", id: 20, job: "university student" }
];

const m = new Map([])
const output = arr.reduceRight((a, o, i) => (m.has(o.name + o.id) || a.push(o) && m.set(o.name + o.id, i), a), [])

console.log(output)
```

However, a regular for loop is the fastest solution here:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "Peter", id: 25, job: "carpenter" },
  { name: "Peter", id: 25, job: "shelf maker" },
  { name: "John", no: 20, job: "student" },
  { name: "John", id: 20, job: "university student" },
  { name: "John", id: 20, job: "student at uni still" },
  { name: "Jack", id: 20, job: "university student" }
];

const m = new Map([])
const out = []

for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const o = arr[i]
  if (!m.has(o.name + o.id)) {
    out.push(o)
    m.set(o.name + o.id, i)
  }
}


console.log(out)
```

See the performance test [here](https://jsperf.com/findindex-vs-map) with a larger, shuffled array.

[image: JSPerf]